# Pycharm unresolved reference issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-import

I have a very strange pycharm behavior. I have a project and a folder in it named `core` (see picture for details). In it i have two python files: `AgentMeasurement.py` and `CollectorBase.py`. Now, i want to import type `AgentMeasurement` from `AgentMeasurement.py` in `CollectorBase`, so i write the following: `from AgentMeasurement import AgentMeasurement`. It works fine (when i run script), but Pycharm marks this as unresolved reference. 
[image]

I tried to mark core as Source Root, but then i can't reference it from other folders as package (i.e. `from core.AgentMeasurement import AgentMeasurement`) and can write `from AgentMeasurement import AgentMeasurement` which makes my code unreadable. How can i make Pycharm work correctly in such a case?

Comment: Have you tried `from .AgentMeasurement import AgentMeasurement` (i.e. a *relative* import)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, it throws exception "Parent Module '' isn't loaded" or something like this

Comment: That won't work if you're running `CollectorBase` directly, but will be fine if you import from `core` and use it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i don't need it since my import works well for both scenarios. I need pycharm to understand my import.

Comment: Is `core` a package?  Then you should be able to use the import suggested by @jonrsharpe.

Answer (score 0):

Since `core` is where your PyCharm project is stored, it references the modules from this folder.

By adding `core.XXX` in front of the module, PyCharm drops its warning.

```
from core.AgentMeasurement import AgentMeasurement
```